# Get select "columns" from a sub query in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

Example: I have a table A

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data1 | Col_name 1 | Data9 |
| Data2 | Col_name 2 | Data10 |

table B

| Col_name 1 | Col_name 2 | Col_name 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data3 | Data5 | Data7 |
| Data4 | Data6 | Data8 |

So I need to construct a query as the following:

`select (get list of columns from Column B from table A) from table B`

Actually, I constructed two queries:

1. Get column list
2. With that column alist putting in select

But I need it in a single query.

Comment: Could you share the expected output of this query, if I understood you correctly then you need to use dynamic SQL query.

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to store column names in a table, because column names belong to a database's structure, not to its data. Mixing the two can make querying the data difficult. ahmed is right; you need dynamic SQL here. This means two steps: select all the data you need for building the final query (i.e. the column names), then build that query and run it. You can just as well just `select * from b` and `select column_b from a` and then have your app display only the columns mentioned in the second query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select (select string_agg(Column B, ',') from table A) from table B;
```

Comment: Please do not use white space inside the table name or column name.